# Read CSV files through Python towards Grafana

Tags: python, grafana

I am new towards Grafana, so I am curious that is there any way to read a CSV file through only Python towards Grafana? Or must I send my data on one of those servers (such as Prometheus or Graphite)?

Answer (score 0):

It is complex to for grafana to query from a csv as a datasource.
Some open source solutions in progress.

- https://github.com/ryantxu/file-system-datasource

A good approach would be storing csv into influxdb or timeseries data and pointing it as data source to grafana for reading.

References

- https://medium.com/devops-dudes/install-prometheus-on-ubuntu-18-04-a51602c6256b
- [https://medium.com/swlh/create-grafana-dashboards-with-python-14a6962eb06c#:~:text=Let's%20start%20with%20installation%3A,of%20your%20datasource%20in%20grafana](https://medium.com/swlh/create-grafana-dashboards-with-python-14a6962eb06c#:%7E:text=Let%27s%20start%20with%20installation%3A,of%20your%20datasource%20in%20grafana)

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be Grafana Infinity Datasource plugin https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/yesoreyeram-infinity-datasource/ which is also available on Grafana Cloud free plan.

It can fetch and show CSV and other data formats from API's and show them as tables on dashboard.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35349083)